# Nested Filter array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, nested

I want to filter the second array, cards, so that it only shows records specified in the cardsfFilter array which is in the first object ( id=1) in the groups.cardsFilter array

**ARRAYS AND REQUIRED RESULT ARE BELOW**

```
const groups = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Melbourne Bands',
//Below is the array that I need to act as the filter for the cards array
    cardsFilter: [1, 2]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Sydney Bands',
    cardsFilter: [3]
  }
]

const cards =  [
  {
    id: '1',
    url: 'jimmyyukka.com',
    name: 'Jimmy Yukka',
    CreatedByUserId: 1
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    url: 'jimmyyukka.com',
    name: 'Due North',
    CreatedByUserId: 1
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    url: 'jimmyyukka.com',
    name: 'INXS',
    CreatedByUserId: 1
  }
]


const desiredResult = [
  {
    id: '1',
    url: 'jimmyyukka.com',
    name: 'Jimmy Yukka',
    CreatedByUserId: 1
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    url: 'jimmyyukka.com',
    name: 'Due North',
    CreatedByUserId: 1
  },
]
```

I am struggling to figure it out and can't find an example on stack overflow for this simple approach.

**I HAVE TRIED (one record)**
I can't figure out how to do this with the array

```
const notQuiteRight= cards.filter(function(getFile){
  return getFile.id === "1"
});
```

Comment: So you only want to use the array in the first object as the filter?

Comment: yes so I need in effect to filter the cards array with the array cardsFilter: [1, 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the property `cardsFilter` from first object of `groups` array and then use filter on `cards` array.

```js
const groups = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Melbourne Bands',
    //Below is the array that I need to act as the filter for the cards array
    cardsFilter: [1, 2]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Sydney Bands',
    cardsFilter: [3]
  }
]

const cards = [{
    id: '1',
    url: 'jimmyyukka.com',
    name: 'Jimmy Yukka',
    CreatedByUserId: 1
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    url: 'jimmyyukka.com',
    name: 'Due North',
    CreatedByUserId: 1
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    url: 'jimmyyukka.com',
    name: 'INXS',
    CreatedByUserId: 1
  }
]


const { cardsFilter } = groups[0];

const desiredOutput = cards.filter(({id}) => cardsFilter.includes(+id));

console.log(desiredOutput);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! A simple , elegant solution but I was faffing about for ages trying to figure it out